# Binding a Vue property to an asynchronous value

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, asynchronous

I have a Vue block that I need to bind to a boolean property:

```
<div class="row" v-if.sync="isThisAllowed">
```

To calculate that property I need to make an API call using Axios, which has to be asynchronous. I've written the necessary code to get the value:

```
public async checkAllowed(): Promise<boolean> {

    var allowed  = false;
    await Axios.get(`/api/isItAllowed`).then((result) => {
        var myObjects = <MyObject[]>result.data.results;
        myObjects.forEach(function (object) {
            if (object.isAllowed == true) {
                hasValuedGia = true;
            }
        })
    });

    return allowed;
}
```

What I did then - I'm not very experienced with Vue - is to add a property to the Vue model and assign a value to it in created:

```
public isThisAllowed: boolean = false;

async created() {
    this.checkAllowed().then(result => {
        this.isThisAllowed = result;
    });
}
```

This works in the sense that the value I'm expecting is assigned to the property. But Vue doesn't like it and complains

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value.

Most of the values on the model are exposed via getters:

```
get isSomethingElseAllowed(): boolean {
    return this.productCode === ProductTypes.AcmeWidgets; 
}
```

But I need to "await" the value of the async function, which would mean making the getter async which then, of course, makes it a Promise and I can't bind that to my model?

What's the right way to go about this?

Comment: You will want to `$emit` a value-changing event for this `isThisAllowed` prop. Refer to the docs [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier).

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a property that way, instead define *isThisAllowed* in the [data object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods)
as

```
data: function(){
    return {
        isThisAllowed: false
    }
}
```

And make `checkAllowed` into a normal function and set `this.isThisAllowed = allowed` inside it